# SparkR drop multi-line header

Tags: r, csv, apache-spark, header, sparkr

How to drop the first n lines (header) of a CSV file read in by SparkR. I know some things are possible in Scala like [How do I convert csv file to rdd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24299427/how-do-i-convert-csv-file-to-rdd) or http://qnalist.com/questions/4849107/skip-lines-in-spark but struggle to apply it to SparkR.

Comment: This is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35844301/working-with-duplicated-columns-in-sparkr/35857226#35857226

You can't drop lines unless you can add a comment character to the lines.  spark-csv CsvRelation.scala does not yet have a method for dropping the first n lines.

Comment: So if I know I want to delete the first 3 lines is this possible at least?

Comment: Do I understand that it would be best to implement something like this in plain scala and then try to access these "external" RDDs from SparkR? Or would you rather go with  http://www.h2o.ai/ which seems to have a fairly comprehensive R API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to use something like this:

```
my_id <- createDataFrame(sqlContext, data.frame(my_id = 1:count(data)))
data.new <- merge(data, my_id)
data.filtered <- filter(data.new, data.new$my_id > 4)
```